# Get age of person by subtraction date

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose that I have code as below:

```
$('#dateNaissance').datepicker({
        onSelect:function(date){
        var today=new Date();
        console.log(today.getTime());
        console.log(new Date(date));
        console.log(DateDiff(today,new Date(date)));

        $('#txtage').val(DateDiff(today,new Date(date)));


        }        


    });


    function DateDiff(date1,date2) {
        return (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
    }
    <tr>
        <td>Date de naissance :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtdob" class="validate[required] text-input datepicker TextInput"  id="dateNaissance"/></td>
        <td>Age :<br /><input type="text" name="txtage" class="validate[required] TextInput" id="txtage"/></td>
    </tr>
```

**I need:**

when the user select date from date picker,it will calculate automatic with date now to get the result in `<td>Age :<br /><input type="text" name="txtage" class="validate[required] TextInput" id="txtage"/></td>` ex:`23 year`.

**Problem**

When I do follow as the code above,it will have the result as the number in `<td>Age :<br /><input type="text" name="txtage" class="validate[required] TextInput" id="txtage"/></td>` ex:`1954172067`.I do not know how to fix this.Anyone help me please,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the code below can help you:

```
 $('#dateNaissance').datepicker({
        onSelect:function(date){
        var today=new Date();
        console.log(today.getTime());
        console.log(new Date(date));
        console.log(DateDiff(today,new Date(date)));        
        $('#txtage').val(DateDiff(today,new Date(date)));       
        }        
});
    function DateDiff(date1,date2) {
        var val = (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
        var days = Math.round(val /1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
        var years = Math.round(days /365);
        return years;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That number you're getting is the seconds between the two dates. All you need to do is divide it into the scope you require. For example, days would be `days = Math.round(x / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24)`

Comment: Math.round(x / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24)

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you #*slaps head*# haven't had my coffee yet ;)

Comment: Thanks,but if I want to get year so how would the number I divide with?

Comment: Divide it be a further `365` to get years